# problem with square brackets in zip function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip

I have a problem with output square brackets instead round.

My code is;

```
def pairs(lst):
    return list(zip(lst, lst[::-1]))[:round(7/2)]
```

I want to get output like this:

```
[[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5], [4, 4]]
```

At the moment my output is:

```
[(1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 4)]
```

Can you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the tuples () to lists [] like this:

```
def pairs(lst):
    return list(map(lambda x: list(x), zip(lst, lst[::-1])))
```

But if you don't need to modify the tuples of the result there's no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
def pairs(lst): 
    return [list(tp) for tp in list(zip(lst, lst[::-1]))]
```

And another, without this transformation

```
def pairs(lst): 
    return [[a,b] for a,b in zip(lst, lst[::-1])]
```

This code just transforms tuples (from your example) to lists. As well I did not really got the purpose of `[:round(7/2)]`  this part ...